# Game theory mixed strategy on a 3x3 Matrix. Finding which actions a player will randomize over.

Tags: game-theory, economics

[image: Problem at Hand]

I have spent a huge amount of time trying to find the mixed strategy equilibria of this game, and unfortunately, I keep getting to no answer.

**My answers worked through**

For (a), it is obvious that the pure strategy of this game is (3,3). It is a given when using the simple method of starring the best strategy given the other player's strategy,

(b) & (c) is where I start to get stuck. I am guessing I need to find the mixed strategy in order to know if the row player is randomizing over 2 or 3 of her actions.

For the expected payoffs of the row player, I wrote them accordingly:
The payoff of the strategy given probability $q$,
$$E(U) = (3)q_1 + (0)q_2 + 0(1-q_1 -q_2)$$
$$E(M) = (0)q_1 + (5)q_2 + (1)(1-q_1 - q_2)$$
$$E(D) = (0)q_1 + (1)q_2 + (5)(1-q_1 - q_2)$$

These simplify to
$$E(U) = (3)q_1$$
$$E(M) = (4)q_2 - q_1 +1$$
$$E(D) = -(4)q_2 -(5)q_1 + 5$$

At this point I solve for either q_1 or q_2:

$$E(M) = E(D)$$
$$(4)q_2 - q_1 +1 = -(4)q_2 -(5)q_1 + 5$$
$$8q_2 + 4q_1 = 4$$
$$2q_2 + q_1 = 1$$
$$q_1 = (1 - 2q_2)$$

This is the exact part I begin to get a little mixed up. I am not sure where to plug this in or, more specifically, where it is most appropriate to plug this in.

I decided to plug it into $E(U) = E(D)$:

$$(3)(1-2q_2) = -4q_2 - 5(1-2q_2) + 5 $$
$$3-6q_2 = -4q_2 -5 + 10q_2 + 5$$
$$3 = 12q_2$$
$$q_2 = 1/4$$

Now I plug in  $q_2$ into the $q_1$ term:

$$q_1 = (1- 2q_2) = 1/2$$.

This leaves the probability of the row going player down to $(1- 1/2 - 1/4) = 1/4$. I have a few questions because I feel iffy about this game theory material.

1. Is my work done correctly?
2. With this information, would I be able to conclude the answer for (b) is she will randomize over M and D since they are both $1/4$?
3. If that is not correct. How do I go about this? How can the row player randomize over 3 actions? It does not seem possible in this case. I have been searching and clawing for hours trying to grasp this. Any information would help tremendously.

Comment: Ad 3.) We have $q_1+q_2+q_3=1$. Thus $q_3=\frac14$. Btw, accepting answers is welcomed.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean? I would like constructive input. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? I think my comment is clear.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three Nash equilibrium:

1. $(U, L)$ (by the way $(3,3)$ in your answer is not a Nash equilibrium...)
2. mixing $(M, P)$ and mixing $(C,R)$ with probability $(1/2, 1/2)$ each, and giving a probability of $0$ to rest. This is the case where the row player mixes exactly two of his strategy.
3. mixing $(U, M, P)$ and mixing $(L, C,R)$ with probability $(1/2, 1/4, 1/4)$ each. This is the case where the row player mixes exactly three of his strategy.

The last Nash equilibrium may seem to be a bit surprising, because it seems that once the row player start to play $M$ or $P$, there is no chance of ever playing $U$ again. But in fact this strategy does just as well. Because if the row player for some reason switch to $U$, then the column player is forced to play $L$, which does just as good in expectation as compared to randomizing over $M, P$